# JS Function executing before AngularJS initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, replace, match

I've been stuck on that since a few hours (I'm not especially good in JS/Angular by the way) and also looked for answers, but couldn't find my way out, so here's my problem:
I have a function which aim is to replace what it founds between brackets in a text by something else, the matter is that I think the function is running before AngularJS, and my text is called by AngularJS (sorry if I have troubles explaining it in english). So, I'm searching on how execute the fonction after, or Angular before. Here are the parts of the code needed

HTML:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li ng-repeat="prop in props" ng-class="cssPropState(prop.state)" ng-click="checkProp(prop)" replace-directive>
         <p class="txtProps">{{prop.value}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
exo2.directive("replaceDirective", function(){
    return function (scope, elements, attrs){
            var mytext = document.getElementsByClass("txtProps");
            var pattern = /\[(.*?)\]/g;
            var results = mytext.firstChild.nodeValue.match(pattern);
            mytext = mytext.replace(results[0], "TEST1");
            mytext = mytext.replace(results[1], "TEST2");
    }
  }
)
```

The text is called by {{prop.value}} and already contains brackets. My issue is that results returns always null, because it can't find the text, because it has not been initialized by Angular yet. Hope my problem is understood, and hope someone will be nice enough to help me !

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move `replace-directive` down to the `<p id="txtProps">`, like this:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li ng-repeat="prop in props" ng-class="cssPropState(prop.state)" ng-click="checkProp(prop)">
         <p id="txtProps" replace-directive>{{prop.value}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now, the element of the link function is the p element, so the link function would look like:

```
exo2.directive("replaceDirective", function($timeout){
    return function (scope, element, attrs){
        $timeout(function() {
            var mytext = element.html();
            var pattern = /\[(.*?)\]/g;
            var results = mytext.match(pattern);
            mytext = montext.replace(results[0], "TEST1");
            mytext = montext.replace(results[1], "TEST2");
            element.html(mytext);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried this, but the problem persists. The text returned in the variable is still {{prop.value}} instead of the actual text that Angular brought after the page was fully loaded

Comment: @Netero_sama I just updated my answer, please check. The solution is you need to call scope.$eval to get the actual value of {{prop.value}}.

Comment: Okay, thanks for updating, tried this again, but it gave an error about [$parse:syntax]. After looking a bit, I found that $eval couldn't evaluate Javascript expressions, apparently only AngularJS ones..

Comment: @Netero_sama It's my mistake, $eval won't work like that. You're seeing `{{prop.value}}` is that angular is still in the linking phase, you need to wait for linking phase to be done. What you'll need is a simple `$timeout`, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yeeeeees this is working !! Although I removed scope.$eval, I just let element.html() as in your first answer, and now, thanks to $timeout, this is actually working. Thanks a lot man !

Comment: @Netero_sama That's right, `scope.$eval` shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

Update: 
Best way to modify a text in {{}} expression is using filter.

You can define a filter like this:

```
exo2.filter('replaceFilter', function(){
    return function(input) {
       var pattern = /\[(.*?)\]/g;
       var result = input.match(pattern);
       var mytext;
       mytext = montext.replace(results[0], "TEST1"); // Here is something broken. montext is undefined. You need fix this.
       mytext = montext.replace(results[1], "TEST2");
       return mytext;
    }
});
```

Then, use filter in html

```
<ul class="list">
    <li ng-repeat="prop in props" ng-class="cssPropState(prop.state)" ng-click="checkProp(prop)">
        <p class="txtProps">{{prop.value | replaceFilter }}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

when you directive **replaceDirective** is compiled. the ng-repeat directive has not finished yet. So you should wait for its completion or find an children element in a $watch execution.

```
exo2.directive("replaceDirective", function(){
    return function (scope, element, attrs){
        scope.$watch({
           var mytext = element.children('.txtProps'); // use class not id
           if(mytext.length) {
              var pattern = /\[(.*?)\]/g;
              var results = mytext.text().match(pattern);
              mytext = montext.replace(results[0], "TEST1");
              mytext = montext.replace(results[1], "TEST2");
              element.html(mytext);
           }
        });

    }
});
```

PS: you shouldn't use id inside ng-repeat. id should be unique in document.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First it gave me a few syntax errors, but weird ones, like saying that it was missing : before var mytext. So I did try to solve all that, and finally obtained something working, but the results were still returning null

Comment: (sorry for double comment) but I still think that maybe $watch can help here, saw it on several threads

Comment: $watch will execute many times during $digest. Maybe you should change you strategy to write a **filter** to filter the text. like this `{{prop.value | someFilter }}` . Here is the official guide https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: I have updated my answer with a filter example added (The code may not used directly, It contains some errors)

Comment: Thanks for keep helping. I updated the code up here, it was indeed a bad idea to put an id, so made a class, and also about montext, it was an error from me, it's actually mytext. I'll try making it work with a filter and your tips now, I'll keep this updated

Comment: Problem solved, I think a $timeout was needed and some more modifications you told me. Thanks again !